# I want to search text in pages using OOTB search function for SPO modern UI

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results, modern-experience, modern-pages

My modern SharePoint Online site has many pages and I want to display the text in those pages in the search results.(The search is OOTB search in the SPO header.)

Is it possible to customize this OOTB search to find text on pages?

I would appreciate any idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the modern search experience cannot be customized.

According to my test, we can find the page through the search text in the SharePoint Online page.

[image]

Comment: There are a number of settings related to search on the site settings page, can't I use those?

Comment: Of course, you can use these OOB settings, I mean, apart from these, we can’t make custom changes to modern search.